# can a conditional format insert a comment if there is a duplicate cell in a column?

Tags: excel-2007

can a conditional format insert a comment if there is a duplicate cell in a column?   If any cell in column "A" is a duplucate, then I want the cell highlighted to  color blue and the comment to say "duplicate part_ID".  please advise and provide me with complete code for me to copy and paste and  instructions. 
thank you very much, Nathaniel

Answer (score 0):

Comments cannot be added, but an adjacent cell could house a warning message that is visible or not based on the condition.